# Отключение рекламы путем ввода кода

Tags: android, google-play, лицензирование, реклама, встроенная-реклама

Возникла необходимость отключения рекламы путем ввода кода в настройках приложения. Т.е. платная версия приложения и покупка in-app не подходит. Как к такому решению относится Гугл?

Comment: Пока вы код распространяете не за плату - гуглу без разницы =)

Comment: Так и хотел - небольшой группе людей выдать этот код.